# How to sort stream data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show all chatroom based on lastmessagetime

How to implement my stream to have sorted chatroom.

how to sort following stream

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("chatrooms").orderBy("lastmessagetime",descending: false).where("participants.${widget.usermodel.uid}", isEqualTo: true).snapshots(),
```

Comment: this one showing error

Comment: What's the error being shown?

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe more detail about your problem?

your code,

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("chatrooms").orderBy("lastmessagetime",descending: false).where("participants.${widget.usermodel.uid}", isEqualTo: true).snapshots(),
```

Comment: Its simple, I want to sort my stream data by a filed named lastmessagetime, and I have tried too... but not working...